# Need help in filtering records according to set of rules with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, spark-graphx

I need help in one of the usecases that I have encountered of filtering records against a set of rules with Apache Spark.

As the actual data has too many fields, for example, you can think of data like below (for simplicity giving data in JSON format),

```
records : [{
             "recordId": 1, 
             "messages": [{"name": "Tom","city": "Mumbai"}, 
                         {"name": "Jhon","address": "Chicago"}, .....]
           },....]

rules : [{
           ruleId: 1,
           ruleName: "rule1",
           criterias: {
                          name: "xyz",
                          address: "Chicago, Boston"
                      }
          }, ....]
```

I want to match all records against all rules. Here is the pseudocode:

```
 var matchedRecords = []
 for(record <- records)
    for(rule <- rules)
       for(message <- record.message)
           if(!isMatch(message, rule.criterias)) 
               break;
       if(allMessagesMatched) // If loop completed without break
           matchedRecords.put((record.id, ruleId))



 def isMatch(message, criteria) = 
           for(each field in crieteria)
                if(field.value contains comma)
                    if(! message.field containsAny field.value)
                        return false
                else if(!message.field equals field.value) // value doesnt contain comma
                     return false
           return true // if loop completed that means all criterias are matched
```

There are thousands of records containing thousands of messages and there are hundreads of such rules.

What are the approaches to solve such kind of problem ? Any specific module would be helpful like (SparkSQL, Spark Mlib, Spark GraphX)? Do I need to use any third party lib ?

**Approach 1 :**

- Have List[Rules] & RDD[Records]
- Broadcast List[Rules] as they are less in number.
- Match each record with all the rules.

Still in this case there is no parallize computation happening for matching each message with the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I think your suggested approach is good direction. If I have to solve this task I would start from implementing generic trait with method responsible for matching:

```
trait FilterRule extends Serializable {
   def match(record: Record): Boolean
}
```

Then I would implement specific filters e.g.:

```
class EqualsRule extends FilterRule
class RegexRule extends FilterRule
```

Then I would implement composite filters e.g.:

```
class AndRule extends FilterRule
class OrRule extends FilterRule
...
```

Then you can filter your rdd or DataSet with:

```
// constructing rule - in reality reading json from configuration, parsing json and creating FilterRule object
val rule = AndRule(EqualsRule(...), EqualsRule(...), ...) 

// applying rule
rdd.filter(record => rule.match(r))
```

Second option is to try using existing Spark SQL functions and DataFrame for filtering, where you can build pretty complex expressions using and, or, multiple columns. Drawback of this approach it is not type safe and unit testing would be more complex.